# retrieve data from LLMNR packet with scapy

Tags: python, scapy

When I look at LLMNR Query pocket with Scapy I see that the LLMNR-Query have inside a DNSQR.
When I like to retrieve data from the LLMNR-Query I can with:

```
pkts[x].sprintf("%LLMNRQuery.qr%")
```

but I didn’t figure out how to retrieve data from the DNSQR that inside the LLMNR-Query; I tried :

```
pkts[x].sprintf("%DNSQR.qname%")`
```

but the unser I get is '??'

I'd be happy to know how to retrieve the DNSQR

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
pkts[x].qd.sprintf('%DNSQR.qname%')
```

Or:

```
pkts[x].qd.qname
```